# ¿Cómo se pueden obtener los siguientes datos de una captura de wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

Alguien sabe como encontrar los datos de Longitud de la cabecera y longitud de los datos en Wireshark para las siguientes capas, no lo veo claro los datos que tengo son "inventados"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería un ejemplo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Y dónde está la captura de wireshark en la que estás buscando eso? Inténtalo y vuelve con una pregunta específica donde hayas intentado resolver tu problema. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta.

Comment: ¿Como que los datos que tienes son inventados?

Comment: Llevas un par de preguntas ya tratando de que alguien venga y haga tu ejercicio o tarea por ti. Busca, inténtalo y donde haya dudas específicas, tráelas.

Comment: Buenas tardes, no es mi intención que me lo hagan en todo caso quiero que corrijan mis interpretaciones, en este caso es que me da miedo que haya datos privados de MAC, por eso no subí la captura de wireshark y en la anterior puse la que creía que era la correcta para mi. Aquí únicamente de cualquier petición de estas características donde se extraen dichos datos en Wireshark. Con inventados quiero decir que lo puse por un campo length pero no entiendo de donde sale en wireshark esos datos en las cadenas.

Comment: pues los datos son necesarios; como podemos darte una respuesta si no podemos reproducir el escenario??? XD